# xpath to select elements with last child value

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

This is my xml file

```
<profiles>
 <profile id='8404'>
  <name>john</name>
  <name>mark</name>
 </profile>
 <profile id='8405'>
  <name>john</name>
 </profile>
</profiles>
```

and I want to select profiles where last "name" child value= john, the result should contains the profile with id=8405 only
what it the xpath that can evaluate this?

here is my trial:

```
     var filterdFile = profilefileXML.XPathSelectElements("/profiles/profile[name[last()]='john']");
```

but it doesn't make sense.

Updated:
My trail is correct, there was only a syntax error in it. Thanks all

Comment: Your xpath should work, i.e. return the profile element with `id=8405`. If you want just the id of the profile, then you need to add `/@id`, i.e. `/profiles/profile[name[last()]='john']/@id`

Answer (score 3):

You can apply multiple indexing operations with successive `[...]`:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml); //the xml from your question

var node = doc.XPathSelectElement("/profiles/profile[name='john'][last()]");

Console.WriteLine(node.Attribute("id").Value); //outputs 8405
```

This will return the last `profile` element that contains the element `name` with a value of `john`.

If you on the other hand want to return **all elements** which last `name` element has a value of `john`, your XPath should work already:

```
var nodes = doc.XPathSelectElements("/profiles/profile[name[last()]='john']");
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Attribute("id").Value);
}
```

Comment: This will return the last profile containing 'john' - I think OP wants all profiles with the last child `name = 'john'`. e.g. Add the following profile at the end of the list `<profile id='8406'>
<name>john</name> <name>bob</name>`

Comment: I think I possibly misunderstood the question. Updated my answer. Thanks for pointing it out to me!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try LINQ

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
var matches = xDoc.Descendants("profile")
              .Where(profile => XElement.Parse(profile.LastNode.ToString()).Value == "john");
```

And you can access the xml data with a foreach

```
foreach(XElement xEle in lastEle)
{
   var xAttribute = xEle.Attribute("id");
   if (xAttribute != null)
   {
       var id = xAttribute.Value;
   }
   var lastName = XElement.Parse(xEle.LastNode.ToString()).Value;
}
```