# Click on a generic element from a generic list

Tags: python, html, tags, robotframework

[The code itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqN7c.png)

Need a help with some ideas how to click on a generic element from a generic list.

For example, I need to select **last** list element, that is `<div class="venue-item">`, from the following list: `<div id="list">`. And click on the following tag `<a href="#" class="venue-actions dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>`

May be to create a Python library?

```
<div id="list" class="row" style="opacity: 1;">
  <div class="venue-item">
      <a class="venue-actions dropdown-toggle" data toggle="dropdown" href="#"></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <h3>test_by_alex_lggge</h3>
      <a class="show-details-btn" href="#">
  <div class="venue-item">
      <a class="venue-actions dropdown-toggle" data toggle="dropdown" href="#"></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <h3>test_by_alex_lggge</h3>
      <a class="show-details-btn" href="#">
  <div class="venue-item">
      <a class="venue-actions dropdown-toggle" data toggle="dropdown" href="#"></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <h3>test_by_alex_lggge</h3>
      <a class="show-details-btn" href="#">
  <div class="venue-item">
      <a class="venue-actions dropdown-toggle" data toggle="dropdown" href="#"></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <h3>test_by_alex_lggge</h3>
      <a class="show-details-btn" href="#">
  <div class="venue-item">
      <a class="venue-actions dropdown-toggle" data toggle="dropdown" href="#"></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <h3>test_by_alex_lggge</h3>
      <a class="show-details-btn" href="#">
  <div class="venue-item">
      <a class="venue-actions dropdown-toggle" data toggle="dropdown" href="#"></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <h3>test_by_alex_lggge</h3>
      <a class="show-details-btn" href="#">
  <div class="venue-item">
      <a class="venue-actions dropdown-toggle" data toggle="dropdown" href="#"></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <h3>test_by_alex_lggge</h3>
      <a class="show-details-btn" href="#">
  <div class="item-detail">
      <a class="venue-actions dropdown-toggle" data toggle="dropdown" href="#"></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <h3>test_by_alex_lggge</h3>
      <a class="show-details-btn" href="#">
 </div>
 <div class="organisation-details">
 <div id="delete-schedule-26681" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? Have you read through the xpath documentation to learn how to access the nth item in a group, for example?

Comment: Yes, I've read through xpath documentation, but there is only ideas for clearly defined elements. But in my case the list of elements could be flexible, if today for example was 6 elements, then tomorrow could be 9 elements. I guess that I should count the list, then to detect last element and after that to click on a needed child from the last element of the list.

Comment: @Alex can you be more specific in the question, what element do you want to target. If you want to always get the last element, that's doable; if you want to get it by its textual value, also. But saying "a generic" means nothing - there should be some pattern you are after.

Comment: I believe you can select the last element using xpath. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508130/xpath-to-select-elements-with-last-child-value

Comment: @Todor , yes, at the moment I need to select last element from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the last `<div>` with `class="venue-item"`, use this xpath:

```
(//div[@id="list"]/div[@class="venue-item"])[last()]
```

Some explanations - the first part (`//div[@id="list"]`) gets all elements with such id value (in your sample - 1). The second (`div[@class="venue-item"]`) selects all of its direct descendants - this will get us a list of all the `div` with such class. The last part - `[last()]` will return the last element of the returned list.

The brackets around part 1 & 2 are here, because of [xpath precedence and scope of axes and operators](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev).
In this particular set it is not needed, but if the connector b/n the 1st part and the 2nd was `//`, it would made a big difference.